# Using PHP, loop and update certain records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement, for-loop

#### Question

I have to award my members with some bonuses on completion of certain tasks.
If they have achieved task1, new the task will be task2

If they have achieved task2, new the task will be task3

If they have achieved task3, new the task will be task4

If they have achieved task4, new the task will be task5

#### Database

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $offername[] = $row['name'];
    $offertask1[] = $row['task1'];
    $offertask2[] = $row['task2'];
    $offertask3[] = $row['task3'];
    $offertask4[] = $row['task4'];
    $offertask5[] = $row['task5'];
    $offerprize[] = $row['prize'];
    $offercurrent[] = $row['current'];
    $offerpercent[] = $row['percent'];
    $offertask[] = $row['task'];
}

Values:
$offername[]  = (offer1, offer2, offer3 ,offerXX)
$offertask1[] = (100,150,200 ,taskxx)
$offertask2[] = (100,150,200 ,taskxx)
$offertask3[] = (100,150,200 ,taskxx)
$offertask4[] = (100,150,200 ,taskxx)
$offertask5[] = (100,150,200 ,taskxx)
$offerprize[] = (5000,2222,3333 ,taskxx)

$offertask= this will replace it value with $offertask1[]
 ,$offertask2[] to $offertask5[] , depending upon the condition
```

#### My Code

```
for ($i=0;$i<=count($offername);$i++) {

    // Check for existing bonuses first. // Code omitted

    //#### If it's the first bonus ########
    if ($member['count'] == 0 ) {
        if ($offerprize[$i] != 0) {
            $offertask = array_replace($offertask, $offertask1);
            $per = $offercurrent[$i]/$offertask[$i] * 100;
            $offerpercent[$i] == round($per);
        }
    }

    //### If he has claimed one bonus and this is the second bonus #####
    if ($member['count'] == 1 ) {
        if ($offercurrent[$i] >= $offertask1[$i] AND $offercurrent[$i] < $offertask2[$i]) {
            if ($offerprize[$i] != 0) {
                $offertask = array_replace($offertask, $offertask2);
                $per = $offercurrent[$i]/$offertask[$i] * 100;
                $offerpercent[$i] == round($per);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have already claimed the first bonus for offer1 == offername[0]. 
I have tested for $offercurrent[0]. It does not work for  ($member['count'] == 1) and so on.

#### Problem

All the values remain same for ($member['count'] == 0 ) and do not change with the count.

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: @CanCelik , please see the edit.

Comment: @CanCelik , I have mentioned the task to be performed in question section. Please let me know which part is not clear.

Comment: What is `$member`? what is you expected behavior?

Comment: Are you sure about the double = in `$offerpercent[$i] == round($per)`? That's odd..

Comment: $offerpercent[$i] == round($per) , this works fine  , no problems with that.

Comment: @RC. $member, random variable to calculate existing bonuses awarded to member

Comment: @RC. expected behaviours is something like this. once member has claimed bonus for task1, next task should change to task2 , to claim the next level  bonus

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php first line in the table I *think* you need `$offerpercent[$i] = round($per)`

Comment: @RC. for the moment we can ignore  $offerpercent[$i] = round($per) , and code will work fine without this. The main focus is how to change the tasks levels.